# SP2013: is content search web part query builder SORTING tab fake?

Tags: query, content-search-web-part

We are using SP2013 on-premise enterprise edition. On a site we use Content Search Web part to show the latest document and pages in entire farm.

In the CSWP query builder, we can list all the document/pages which is expected. However when we work on the "SORTING" tab, whatever we configure the query change nothing. ([This article](http://www.eliostruyf.com/sorting-not-working-in-the-search-results-web-part-with-predefined-query-sharepoint-2013/) also reflect the same problem)

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it a bug and have Microsoft fixed it?
2. Can I manually modify the
   query so that it will sort by "LastModifiedTime"?

It is my existing query:

```
AvailableonparentsiteOWSBOOL=1  (ContentType:"XYZ Base Page" OR 
ContentType:"XYZ Common Page" OR 
ContentType:"XYZ Document") -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

Thank you for advice.

Comment: That article is related to the Search Results webpart, which needs to have the sort dropdown visible to sort. You are talking about the Content by Search webpart, which is not the same webpart

Comment: I think you're correct. But I still cannot sort the result correctly. Strangely the XYZ Document have higher priority than Base Page or Common Page even it has an ealier modified date.